# How can I set font for multi lingual text in ms word document in c#?

Tags: c#, ms-word

I create a .docx file with multi lingual content. Arabic & English. When I set font name and size to my text, I can't change font of Arabic text. Just run on english text. How can I change my below code to set font on all text. Please help me!

```
Word.Paragraph wordParagraph = wordDoc.Paragraphs.Add(ref objMissing);
wordParagraph.Range.Font.Name = "B Titr";
wordParagraph.Range.Font.Size = 14;
wordParagraph.Range.Text = RtbResult.Text;
wordParagraph.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To set the font for Right-to-Left text, use the Font.NameBi property instead of Font.Name.

So, in your code above, you would write:

```
wordParagraph.Range.Font.NameBi = "B Titr";
```

Answer (score 0):

And if you want to change the font size it will be

```
wordParagraph.Range.Font.SizeBi = 12f
```